# I am having ubuntu 16.04 LTS and i have to run Citrix Reciever on it

Tags: 16.04, citrix

For that i am following the solution provided https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

But whenever i run the command below command

```
sudo apt-get install libmotif4:i386 nspluginwrapper lib32z1 libc6-i386 libxp6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libasound2:i386
```

I get the below output

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmotif4:i386
E: Unable to locate package nspluginwrapper
E: Unable to locate package libxp6:i386
```

Please tell me what i am missing .

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Receiver download page](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux/receiver-for-linux-latest.html), the latest version is available in 64-bit, and you should just be able to download the amd64 deb and install it on 16.04 without the extra instructions that were 14.04 on the community help page you linked.